# Missing table borders when including bootstrap.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, border

I started using bootstrap in my project.

I am including bootstrap.css on all pages. The problem is that now all my existing tables lost the border.

Here's my principal css:

```
.tabla{
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:8pt;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

It seems like bootstrap.css is overwriting some property. All the files I include my style file first, then bootstrap.css .

Note: the unseen border is the border between the rows. The outer border looks good.

Answer (score 0):

can you just add them to your?

```html
.tabla {
 font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:8pt;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-style: solid;
    }
```

Remember to add the bootstrap css in your html **before** your own custom css file like this :

```
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Personal CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```